# Disabling Javascript execution when loggining in

Tags: php, javascript

I have an `Index.php` page that launches a `JQuery` dialog (in `modal` mode). Dialog consists of a login form. When form gets submitted an `Ajax request` is sent to another php file (where the request gets handled). If request is succeded I just close the dialog.

I know I can use `<noscript>` tag. But what if I disable `javascript`, at any time I wish?. Is it possible to respond (redirect user to a login page) dynamically?

Thanks!

Comment: Disabling javascript takes a page refresh to take effect. Probably. At least in chrome. And firefox.

Comment: 99,99% of the browser have javascript enabled by default and users rarely disable it. the most solid solution i believe it to use a noscript tag and ask user to either enable javascript or visit a url to a page that handles requests from browser with javascript disabled.

Comment: Yes I know. But I'm confused whether javascript-disabling, especially in IE, triggers page to refresh (so it could then use <noscript>)? Maybe I don't quite understand the flow. But I thought that '<noscript>' gets handled on load?

Answer (score 2):

This will helps you ..
If the script was turned off in the page this will  automatically redirect the page to the specified url in the given  meta tag 
and if java script is enabled it will comment the redirecting  meta tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  document.write("<!"+"--") </script> <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=noscript.html"> <!--//-->
```

Answer (score 1):

I never did this but have you tried to put this in the `<header>` :

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/other-page.html">
</noscript>
```

I don't know if the solution works, but it's possible it does :)

Comment: it cannot be nested in <head>. It should be nested within <body> tag

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys!

After searching it comes out that making it like:

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/other-page.html">
</noscript>
```

is quite dirty regarding to html validness (`<head>` tag not supposed to nest `<noscript>` tag, neither body supposed to contain `<meta>` tag). Also I've read that it's possible to supress the effect/use of

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/other-page.html">
```

Well. So there's a scenario came to my mind:

```
<body>
    <noscript><?php /* ?></noscript> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="some_actionA.php"></li>
        <li><a href="some_actionB.php"></li>
        <li><a href="some_actionC.php"></li>
    </ul>
    <noscript><?php */ ?><p class="note">to proceed: Turn on Javascript!</p></noscript>
</body>
```

No need to make redirects!

**Edit**

Oops..

It cleans `<body>` even if `Javascript` is enabled( So I ended up with two pages `Login.php` and `Index.php`. Inside `Login.php` I check for javascript support. If that's not supported message is shown to the user.