# How to disable the execution of JavaScript in a simple way?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, noscript

I want to measure the HTML parsing time of some webpages. One difficulty is the parsing and JavaScript execution happen alternatively.

I am not familiar with html and javascript, is there any simple way to disable the execution of the scripts?

E.g. inserting `<noscript>` to some places (I am not sure if this will work)

By the way, I do experiments on Android.

Comment: did you tried this method?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575839/disabling-javascript-execution-when-loggining-in

Answer (score 3):

You can disable JavaScript in Chrome developer tools. Click on settings icon on lower right of the tool then you will find the settings.

[image]

Comment: The question is about doing this on Android.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type

   chrome://settings/content

   in Chrome browser address bar.
2. Under JavaScript section select "Do not allow any site to run JavaScript".
3. Click Done.
4. Refresh page, JavaScript will not be executed.